# Check quantization status of model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, quantization

I have a Keras (not tf.keras) model which I quantized (post-training) to run it on an embedded device.

To convert the model to a quantized tflite model, I tried different approaches and ended with around five versions of quantized models. They all have slightly different size but they all seem to work on my x86 machine. All models show different inference timings.

Now, I would like to **check how the models are actually quantized** (fully, only weights,... ) as the embedded solution only takes a fully quantized model. And I want to see more details, e.g., what are the differences in weights (maybe explaining the different model size). the model summary does not give any insights.

- Can you give me a tip on how to go about it?
- Does anyone know if the tflite conversion with the TF1.x version is always fully quantized?

Thanks

---

**More explanation:**

The models should be fully quantized, as I used

```
converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.uint8
```

during conversion. However, I had to use the TF1.x version to transform, or respectively `tf.compat.v1.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file` with TF2.x. so I am not sure about the output model using the "classic" TF1.x version or the  tf.compat.v1. version.

**The way different models were created**

1. Using TF1.3 converting a h5 model
2. using TF1.5.3 converting a h5 model
3. using TF2.2 converting a h5 model
4. converting h5 model to pb with TF1.3
5. converting h5 model to pb with
   TF1.5
6. converting h5 model to pb with TF2.2
7. using TF1.5.3 converting the converted pb models
8. using TF2.2   converting the converted pb models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron) is a handy tool for visualizing networks. You can choose individual layers and see the types and values of weights, biases, inputs and outputs.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this. Looking forward to some nice display. stay save and healthy

Comment: You're welcome. If you use Netron, you should also see that TF1.x should return fully quantized networks.

Comment: You are welcome. If you think the answer is sufficient, please consider accepting it via the green check next to it :)

Comment: :-) I had to check it first in detail. Have a nice day and thank you for your help